# How to get log entries out of the inner apoc.periodic.iterate statement in Neo4j?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4j-apoc

### Initial situation

The [log procedures](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#log) allow us to write values to the log file.
Run in the Neo4j Browser, the statement `Call apoc.log.info('Hello %s', ['Neo4j Community']);` immortalizes the greeting under logs/neo4j.log and logs/debug.log as expected.

If I now try to write the same greeting from a `apoc.periodic.iterate` call into the log, the query itself will be successfully executed and noted in the log, but the desired output will not appear - without an error message.

```
CALL apoc.periodic.iterate('
    RETURN "reduced single test record"
', '
    Call apoc.log.info(\'--> Hello %s\', [\'Neo4j Community\'])
    RETURN true;
', {batchSize: 1000, iterateList: true, parallel: true})
    YIELD
        total, committedOperations, failedOperations, batches, failedBatches, retries, errorMessages, batch, operations, wasTerminated;
```

### Target scenario

How can I get log entries out of the inner `apoc.periodic.iterate` statement?

---

### Update

After upgrading to Neo4j 3.5.8, the issue scenario remains unchanged.
The one-liner output is written correctly to the log (second line), but not from the `apoc.periodic.iterate` statement, although it is noted in the log itself (line 3 to 8).

```
2019-07-29 20:11:10.431+0000 INFO [o.n.i.d.DiagnosticsManager] --- SERVER STARTED END ---
2019-07-29 20:12:37.425+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.p.Procedures] hello_neo4j_community_from_single_line_statement_
2019-07-29 20:13:36.179+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.p.Procedures] starting batching from `
    RETURN "reduced single test record"
` operation using iteration `
    Call apoc.log.info('--> Hello %s from inner statement.', ['Neo4j Community'])
    RETURN true;
` in separate thread
```

Comment: What neo4j version are you using? Your Cypher returns the "desired output" in neo4j 3.5.4 for me.

Comment: @cybersam Neo4j 3.5.7, APOC 3.5.0.4, Neo4j Browser 3.2.20, macOS

Comment: I tried with 3.5.8, and that also works. Try upgrading.

Comment: @cybersam Updated to Neo4j 3.5.8 as suggested. Issue scenario remains unchanged. Please find the according output in question extension.

Comment: @cybersam Two very wild guesses come to my mind:
(I) The difference between the functioning one-liner and the non-appearing log entry from the inner statement is the necessary escaping. Could the error scenario be related to macOS escaping? Is this also the reason why my iterate statement produces output for you and not for me?
(II) The iterate statement is executed "[...] in separate thread". Is it ensured that threads behave the same on all operating systems?